# Get parents by filtering two date range in childs table with Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-4.0

I have two tables with this informations:

> Room

| id | room name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | room 1 |
| 2 | room 2 |

and a child table with this information:

> Reservation

| id | room id (reserved_rooms) | from date | to date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-05-20 | 2022-05-22 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-05-23 | 2022-05-25 |

I want to get available rooms for a certain amount of time:

1. Witch doesn't have any reservation
2. rooms where no reservation has been made at a specific time such as ‍‍`2022-05-24`

I tried the following code, but the problem is that the booked room is returned with **id=1**, while it has a reservation on the desired date.

```
Room.objects.filter(Q(reserved_rooms__isnull=True) | 
                    Q(reserved_rooms__from_date__gt=date) | 
                    Q(reserved_rooms__to_date__lt=date))
```

This query ignored reservation with **id=2**, because `2022-05-23 < 2022-05-24 < 2022-05-25`, but reservation with **id=1** causes that room with **id=1** is returned. because `2022-05-24` not in range `2022-05-20` and `2022-05-22`.
so I expected that the only room with **id=2** would be returned, but both 1 and 2 were returned.

---

What is your suggestion to solve this challenge?

Comment: This seems like two different queries, but you only show one. I wouldn't try to combine the two conditions. Or at least try to do them separately before combining them.

Comment: Trying to do each condition separately will show you that you have an "or" where you should have an "and".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Code-Apprentice, I did what you said

Comment: When I said two separate queries, I meant one for what you describe in #1 and another for #2. Separating the two conditions will help you find the error in your logic. Then you can recombine in a single query.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
qs1 = Room.objects.filter( reserved_rooms__isnull=True ) 
qs2 = Room.objects.exclude( reserved_rooms__isnull=True
      ).exclude( reserved_rooms__from_date__gt=date,
                 reserved_rooms__to_date__lt=date )
      )
result = q1.union(q2)
```

I'm not sure if one has to `.exclude( reserved_rooms__isnull=True)` in qs2, but I doubt it's worth the effort of finding out! The second `exclude` with two arguments is the usual and-logic.

Comment: The first query shouldn't require a `Q` object.

Comment: True. I copied the OP's code then modified it. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I handled it with two separate queries: `Room.objects.all()` and `Reservation.objects.filter(from_date__lte=date, to_date__gte=date)`. Then I removed rooms from the first query response, which these rooms' IDs are in the second query response.

Comment: @AmirhosseinAzhdari note that this is less efficient than using relationships directly in your query such as `reserved_rooms__from_date__gt` and `reserved_rooms__from_date__lt` because it requires two separate queries. When I mentioned two queries, I was referring to the two criteria that you describe in words in your question. The problem with your original code is in the boolean logic.